# Exception Connection refused while connecting Android device to PC

Tags: java, android, http, url

This i the code of Connection

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DL_URL = "http://localhost:8080/project-server/rest/?value=test";
    downloadJsonFile();

}

 private void downloadJsonFile() {
        try {
            createFileAndDirectory();
            URL url = new URL(DL_URL);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();


            int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            Log.v("gg", Integer.toString(status));
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(jsonFile);
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutput.close();
            }else{
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
```

And this is my servles located @my own PC tha I try to connect to it (I use Windows 7)

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 }
```

Erros I get

```
    06-18 12:42:55.940: W/System.err(4740): java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 - Connection refused
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at com.example.test1.MainActivity.downloadJsonFile(MainActivity.java:42)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at com.example.test1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
    06-18 12:42:55.950: W/System.err(4740):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
    06-18 12:42:55.960: W/System.err(4740):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you don't have a firewall maybe?

Comment: You cannot use "localhost" to contact a different computer as it is by definition the computer you are on.  That problem has many duplicate questions here.  You are also headed for a network on main thread exception, another problem with many duplicate questions.

Comment: do you the Internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @ChrisStratton 
This code work fine in above application (another pc)

Comment: @naware, no it does not.  The only way this code can work is if the server is running on the same computer as the client.

Comment: yes in a previous project I use this @ with localhost (with ubuntu) and it work fine so i think the problem is that i currently using windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to access `http://localhost:8080/project-server/rest/?value=test`, but localhost refers to the loopback address 127.0.0.1, so your request is sent to your Android device itself, not to your pc. Change localhost with the ip address of your pc.

Comment: If you try to connect to that url with Android browser, does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Try to connect using "10.0.2.2:8080" instead of using "localhost:8080"

It'll work...

Comment: If you are running both server and emulator in you computer 127.0.0.1:(port) will refer to the emulator itself and not to the server.